# How to pass datatable as a parameter in postgresql?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, asp.net-core, ado.net

I want to pass the dataTable as a parameter in the postgresql function.

```
public void InsertDataInBulk(DataTable dataTable, string functionName ,ILogger logger) 
        {
            try
            {
                var connection = _dbConnect.OpenConnection(logger);
                DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "f_testbulkinsert";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                if (dataTable != null)
                {
                    var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
                    parameter.ParameterName = "testtype";
                    parameter.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable, Formatting.Indented);
                    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                }
                _dbConnect.CloseConnection(connection, logger);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

Here is my postgresql function.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_testbulkinsert(
    testtype varchar)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  
END;
$BODY$;
```

I am trying to pass the data table as a parameter in the postgreSql function by serializing it(That's the only way I could find working in postgresql).
I just want to deserialize the json string into the list of objects and do the bulk insertion in my database.
How can I do that ?

Please help me.
If there is any more info required, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL supports multiple inserts statements in following format.

```sql
    INSERT INTO LaptopBrand (Id,Name,Country) VALUES
        (1, 'Lenovo', 'CHINA'),
        (2, 'Apple', 'US'),
        (3, 'HP','US');
```

You can build the insert command using StringBuilder and execute it.

Also the official [PostgreSQL doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/dml-insert.html) recommends to use [Copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/sql-copy.html) instead of insert statements for bulk inserts.

If you are using Npgsql for connecting to Postgres from your .net project, then you can execute [Copy command](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html) for bulk inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a library such as PgPartner to accomplish bulk inserts very easily. Check out PgPartner: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PgPartner/

https://github.com/SourceKor/PgPartner#bulkadd-npgsqlconnection-extension

Usage:

```
// Domain Model Objects
var samples = new List<Sample>()
{
    new Sample { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test", ItemSum = 200, ItemAmount = 10 },
    new Sample { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test 2", ItemSum = 400, ItemAmount = 20 },
    new Sample { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test 3", ItemSum = 800, ItemAmount = 30 },
    new Sample { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test 4", ItemSum = 1200, ItemAmount = 40 },
    new Sample { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Test 5", ItemSum = 2400, ItemAmount = 50 }
};

// Instantiate and open PostgreSQL database connection
using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("<connection string>");
conn.Open();

// Execute BulkAdd by passing objects to insert into table, single object mapping, database schema, and database table
conn.BulkAdd(
    samples,
    (mapper, sample) => {
        mapper.Map("id", sample.Id, NpgsqlDbType.Uuid);
        mapper.Map("name", sample.Name, NpgsqlDbType.Text);
        mapper.Map("amount", sample.ItemAmount, NpgsqlDbType.Numeric);
        mapper.Map("sum", sample.ItemSum, NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
    },
    "public",
    "\"Samples\""
);
```